# Parse json data to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to parse following json data, but I get following error:

> Invalid array passed in, ',' expected. (19): { '2': { '2_1': [0: 244,
>   1: 837], '2_2': [0: 333, 1: 444] } }

Code

```
var jsonData = @"{ '2': { '2_1': [0: 244, 1: 837], '2_2': [0: 333, 1: 444] } }";
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var x = (Dictionary<string, List<object>>)j.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
```

Any help?

### UPDATE:

Changed to:

```
string jsonData = @"{ 'Two': { 'Two_1': [{0: 244}, {1: 837}], 'Two_2': [{0: 333}, {1: 444}] } }";
```

but now I get following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]`
>   to type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Object]]`.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Always verify you have valid JSON using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). If it's not valid, you can't deserialize it.

Comment: It's still invalid. See my answer - names should be strings

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Please check the data now. I still get error.

Comment: @mrd again, **all** names should be strings. See my answer. Take a look on code sample - both `0` and `1` should be strings. BTW you don't need to use `'Two'` instead of `'2'` - both are valid names

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Can you please correct JSON data variable. How it should be? I am still getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid JSON. If you have array of objects, then it should look like

```
[{'0' : 244}, {'1': 837}]
```

See [JSON syntax](http://json.org/):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

Also keep in mind that names should be strings.

---

Correct JSON:

```
{'2': {'2_1': [{'0': 244}, {'1': 837}], '2_2': [{'0': 333}, {'1': 444}]}}
```

Comment: Ok. I changed. But I get new error. Naming is a requirement!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have got twice the number 0 and 1 as a name? ('0' with the 244 & 333 and '1' with the 837 & the 444)